# PDO PHP __construct() warning?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**What I have**

```
// Make an attempt to connect to the database
    try {
        // Make our connection
        $DataBaseHandle = new PDO($Host,$Username,$Password,$Table);

            $DataBaseHandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
                echo 'Connected!<br/>';

    // This will give us a output as an average 
    $SQLQuery = "SELECT 
                CONCAT('$',TRUNCATE(AVG(`payper`),2)) AS `Average Pay`
                FROM `rep_commission`
                ";

foreach ($DataBaseHandle->query($SQLQuery) as $row)
    {
    echo $row["Average Pay"];
    }

    $DataBaseHandle = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
    }
```

**What I am trying to do**

I am rewriting a bunch of my MYSQL_ files as we all know they're deprecated. I am also trying to prevent injection possibilities for grins. Scripts will be behind a employee dashboard, but want to take extra measures in case we have a smart employee with malicious intent.

Read here [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/12202218#12202218)

`$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` does the trick???

I am also learning :D

I am curious where I am going wrong, as I am getting a

```
E_WARNING : type 2 --
PDO::__construct() expects parameter 4 to be array, string given 
-- at line 11
```

And

```
E_ERROR : type 1 --
Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object
 -- at line 12
```

Where did I go wrong?

Also, if someone could show me how do I do a var_dump(), with the code that I have above. Im having a hard time understanding how to do it properly. Tried reading up on it but was lost :(

Comment: warnings seem clear `$Table` is a string

Comment: Yeah. Do a `var_dump()` of each of your 4 arguments and you should see what the problem is

Comment: @Machavity can you be a little more descriptive please. :)

Comment: @Dagon what would be a viable solution?

Comment: i really would hope that was obvious

Comment: `public PDO::__construct ( string $dsn [, string $username [, string $password [, array $options ]]] )` string, string, string, **array** `options

    A key=>value array of driver-specific connection options.
` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: so public PDO::__construct ( string $Host [, string $Username [, string $Password [, array $Table ]]] ) would be the correct output ?

Comment: have you read the manual page, or even glanced at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91337/discussion-between-levizoesch-and-dagon). @Dagon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Needed to change
From

```
$Table = 'dbname=tablename';
$Host ='mysql:host=$Localhost';
$Localhost='localhost';
$Username='';
$Password='';
```

To

```
$Host ="mysql:host=$Localhost;DBName=database";
$Username='test';
$Password='';
```

And
From

```
 $DataBaseHandle = new PDO($Host,$Username,$Password,$Table);
```

To

`$DataBaseHandle = new PDO($Host,$Username,$Password)`;